# Past tense of people watching (applied to zombies)

Tags: past-tense

My characters in a book are watching zombies, ie people watching, but the people are the walking dead. Anyway, I'm wondering what the correct tense usage is, as I'm writing in past.

'drinking from tea cups while they zombie-watched.' is the exact part of the sentence at present.

Comment: *Zombie-watched* is fine as it stands, but since you've cast *drinking* in the progressive aspect, so you could equally say "*They were drinking from tea-cups while zombie-watch**ing***".

Comment: Jarred sat with Sarah at the gate house to the compound – really just a wall of cars on their sides around nine skyscrapers with Brock Industries in the approximate centre – drinking from tea cups while they zombie-watched. (the original sentence, in UK English) My guts says to end it with 'drinking from tea cups while **zombie-watching**.'

Comment: @DarkWordDan Either phrase works fine, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

As @DanBron says in the comment above, **zombie-watch*ing*** is the normal way to say it.  In this case the sentence is:

> ...drinking from teacups while [they were] zombie-watching.

This is how it would normally be used with people watching.  There is nothing technically wrong with **zombie-watched;** it just sounds more awkward than **zombie-watching.**  Other options include **while they watched for zombies, on their guard for zombies,** and **looking out [or around] for zombies.**